# Does the writing on a mezuzah have to be totally straight?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, safrus

I saw a mezuzah parchment where it seems that the while the letters where all in a line, in the sense that they did not collide with the rows above or below them, but within the row, the letters were not necessarily right next to each other. I.e., some letters were slightly higher or lower than the letter next to them.

Would this still make the mezuzah kosher?

I'll see if I can get a pic of it that I can upload.

Comment: isnt that the point of sirtot?

Comment: @sam Of course it is! But, I assume that there's some flexibility as to how straight things need to be and that may allow some occasional going outside the lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer without a picture. Let's see if this helps.

The scores on the parchment are called *sirtut* and are mandatory on a mezuza ([Hilchot Mezuza 1:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925417/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-One.htm)). They help to write straight.

[R Yerachmiel Askotzky](http://www.stam.net/about_me.aspx) in his book [Tefillin and Mezuzos](http://a.co/gZZ3cz8) writes (p. 136-137)

> If the writing is not in a straight, horizontal line, the parchment is
>   *passul* and irreparable according to all *poskim*. Letters that are written very slightly below the *sirtut* are acceptable. If there is
>   writing clearly below the *sirtut*, some *poskim* say it is still
>   kosher as long as the writing is straight. According to other
>   *poskim*, writing below the *sirtut* will make a parchment *passul*. [...] If the writing is wavy or on an angle, it is *passul* and irreparable.

In other words as long as letters are within the bounds of - or very slightly below/above - the *sirtut* then the mezuza is OK. If they are clearly below/above then you get into a *machloket*.

Net net it is always better to show these questionable parchments to a reputable *sofer*.